# How to solve the error: Cannot find module 'express-rate-limit' in Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using module **express-rate-limit** in express app to limit requests but i got this error when run app: **Cannot find module 'express-rate-limit'** although i was installed this module in node_modules
What i am wrong?

My code below:

```
import express from "express";
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';

const app = express();

app.use('/api', rateLimit({
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 mins
  max: 100,
  message: 'To many requests, please try again later!',
})); 

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('App running on port 3000'))
```

[image: image capture for this error]

Comment: Install it? `npm i express-rate-limit`

Comment: @Vishnudev Yep i was installed it!

Comment: The code works for me. Did you do the npm command inside the folder where the above script is present?

Comment: @Vishnudev I tested and realize that all other modules working fine but except the module express-rate-limit

Comment: Add the full traceback error to the post.

Comment: @Vishnudev I updated my question and attach an image describing the error. Help me check it!

Comment: @Vishnudev I think this error comes from the author of 'express-rate-limit' , I checked the source code this module and found it updated recently

Answer (score -2):

I was found the solution to solve this error, just downgrade to lower version and it works.